# MongoDB MapReduce (1.2) PHP with parameter

Tags: php, mongodb, parameters, mapreduce

I'm trying to 'parameterize' a MongoDB MapReduce on PHP and seem to be hitting a wall. I feel like I'm missing something obvious since I'm not super experienced in PHP or javascript. I can get the map reduce to work and return what I need if I hard code the value I want it to check.

For example

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client;
$collection = $client->selectCollection('collection','responses');        
$map = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript('function() { if(this.response == "Yes") { emit("matches", 1)}};');
$reduce = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript('function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values)};');
$out = ['inline' => 1];

$data = $collection->mapReduce($map, $reduce, $out);

foreach ($data as $d) {
    var_dump($d);
}
```

I would like this *if(this.response == "Yes")* "Yes" value to be a variable so I can filter on other responses.

I've tried a handful of ways and I can't get it to work.

Any tips or ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the query that isn't working look like?

Comment: Thanks for the question, but I think I got it to work now. I knew it was something simple I was just missing. I was trying to 'concatenate' the variable inside the MongoDB\BSON\Javascript call. I just did the concatenation before hand and simply called that function with the new string variable containing the parameter.